# How to input user's input from one function to another function without using class concept

Tags: function

## I am trying to take user's input in one function and want to pass the value #into another function but without using class concept

Comment: negative_responses = ("no", "nope", "nah", "naw", "not a chance", "sorry")

def greet():
    name = input("Hello there ,What is your name ?")
    will_help = input("Hi {}, I'm Etcetera. I'm not from this planet. Will you help me learn about your planet? ".format(name))
    return name, will_help
greet() 
# Define make_exit() here:
def make_exit():
  if will_help == negative_responses:
    print("Ok, have a nice Earth day!")
    return greet()
make_exit()

Comment: Above is my code ..Can somebody please help